# My question was totally misunderstood please reopen it or let me know where should i ask

Tags: discussion

> Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on Super User.

Reason to close the question does not look valid to me, I believe person did not get it correctly.

> questions about home networking

This question was clearly asked about setting up web hosting company like environment to learn, its setup for learning at home. It's not a home network.

> consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic

My question was about using HP V1910-24G switch, which is not a home consumer grade item at all.

[My question was asked here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80590/can-i-route-public-static-ips-on-vlan)

Answer (score 1):

I understood what you are doing, but you can edit the question to remove the references to home networking. Also, remember that residential ISP connections are different than business ISP connections, so you may be limited at home unless you get a business connection.

You also need to include a lot more detail, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models (your host with OPNSense is off-topic, and you can ask about that on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network, although they will close questions about a home network, too), the network device configurations, etc.

We will not design your network for you, but we can answer questions that have specific answers. Remember that SE sites are explicitly not discussion forums, and questions that lead to primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic. We have [Network Engineering Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations) for discussions, opinions, and other off-topic questions, and you have sufficient reputation to participate there.